# How to practice with Spring cloud in local machine?

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud

I am new and just started to explore Spring Cloud. Would like to know how to practice with examples in **local (laptop)**. It appears to need a cloud environment. And most of them are available only for few days. So any  pointers to try out features like 
Distributed/versioned configuration, Service registration and discovery ,Routing Service-to-service calls, Load balancing Circuit and Breakers Global locks

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the Spring guides where we guide you, step by step, to achieve what you have described. You can check out the link here for the Ribbon guide -
https://spring.io/guides/gs/client-side-load-balancing/ and the link to all of the guides https://spring.io/guides/

Comment: Thanks @Marcin . that was helpful. This seems to be Client side load balancing which is good during development. 
As a followup , what would be the next step to test server side load balance testing ? i.e the real cloud scenario.

Comment: You can use the Spring Cloud CLI to easily start a server. You can check out the Spring Cloud samples to see examples of different pieces of Spring Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this blog, service discovery, routing and load balancing. 
[Spring Cloud, Eureka and Zuul](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/02/05/part-1-creating-microservice-using-spring-cloud-eureka-and-zuul/)

For Distributed/versioned configuration, check this one 
[Quick Intro to Spring Cloud Configuration](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration)

Also one example, that brings all of that together [Spring Cloud Bootstrapping](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bootstrapping)